# ssh-keygen -R saying (wrongly) no matches found

Tags: terminal, ssh, zsh

I've come across the not-uncommon issue where ssh keys on a host have changed, so they don't match what's saved in my `~/.ssh/known_hosts` file. When I connect (in this case via an Ansible playbook), it freaks out with "WARNING: REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED!", yada yada yada.

The *usual* fix for this is to run `ssh-keygen -R <host-ip-or-name>`, which deletes the offending entry. In this case the host is an ip:port combo, so I tried to run it like this:

`ssh-keygen -R [xxx.xxx.xx.xxx]:yyyyy`

Instead of updating `known_hosts`, I get a message returned that says:

`zsh: no matches found: [xxx.xxx.xx.xxx]:yyyyy`

I tried running it without the port, just in case (`ssh-keygen -R xxx.xxx.xx.xxx`). That gives a "host not found" error.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

The problem was actually the zsh shell. Given the `[xxx.xxx.xx.xxx]:yyyyy` syntax, zsh was interpreting the `[]`s as a globbing pattern. That's why I was getting a "zsh: no matches found" error.

In the old Bash shell, this isn't a problem, and the command I gave runs perfectly.

The solution in zsh is to quote the whole hostname, like this:

```
ssh-keygen -R "[xxx.xxx.xx.xxx]:yyyyy"
```